# Exclude matched character from output

Tags: shell

I have a script shell with one parameter.

```
./script.sh 121-0/2/3
```

I want to print only after the "-":

Output :

```
0/2/3
```

how to do this in shell ??

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `$ { variable # pattern }` 
If the pattern matches the beginning of the variable's value, delete the shortest part that matches and return the rest.

In your case:

```
var = $1 #(command line argument)
res = ${var # *-} #Wrong: spaces
res = ${var#*-} #gives your response
```

For instance you can look up it [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch04_03.htm)

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work     ${port # *-}: bad substitution

Comment: this solution give the hole line 121-0/2/3  and not 0/2/3

Comment: I works perfectly in my shell. `echo $res` gives me the desired: `0/2/3`

Comment: Thank you it works now ... i didn't gave the right parameter .